# How to set Ajax call & for each loop for a dynamic dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, dropdown

#### Problem

I'm trying to make a dynamic dropdown, I have already made a static one. I want to get dropdown value from a JSON file.

How do I solve this problem?

#### HTML

```
<div class="main-drop-down">
        <div class="drop-cat">
            <ul class="list-unstyled custom-li">
                <li class="item-cat">
                    Echo & Alexa
                    <i class="fas fa-chevron-right float-right"></i>
                    <div class="sub-cat-section">
                        <div class="ul-sub-cat">
                            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                <li class="list-sub-cat">
                                    <a href="#" class="sub-link">
                                        first
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="list-sub-cat">
                                    <a href="#" class="sub-link">
                                        first
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="list-sub-cat">
                                    <a href="#" class="sub-link">
                                        first
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="list-sub-cat">
                                    <a href="#" class="sub-link">
                                        first
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="list-sub-cat">
                                    <a href="#" class="sub-link">
                                        first
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <img src="https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/31/img18/AmazonDevices/Neel/GW/500x450_Flyout-new._CB456065619_.png"
                            alt="img" class="img-fluid" />
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="item-cat">
                    Fire Tv Stick
                    <i class="fas fa-chevron-right float-right"></i>
                    <div class="sub-cat-section">
                        <div class="ul-sub-cat">
                            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                <li class="list-sub-cat">
                                    <a href="#" class="sub-link">
                                        first
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="list-sub-cat">
                                    <a href="#" class="sub-link">
                                        first
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="list-sub-cat">
                                    <a href="#" class="sub-link">
                                        first
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="list-sub-cat">
                                    <a href="#" class="sub-link">
                                        first
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="list-sub-cat">
                                    <a href="#" class="sub-link">
                                        first
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="item-cat">
                    Kindle E-Reader & eBook
                    <i class="fas fa-chevron-right float-right"></i>
                    <div class="sub-cat-section">
                        <div class="ul-sub-cat">
                            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                <li class="list-sub-cat">
                                    <a href="#" class="sub-link">
                                        first
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="list-sub-cat">
                                    <a href="#" class="sub-link">
                                        first
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="list-sub-cat">
                                    <a href="#" class="sub-link">
                                        first
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="list-sub-cat">
                                    <a href="#" class="sub-link">
                                        first
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="list-sub-cat">
                                    <a href="#" class="sub-link">
                                        first
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="item-cat">
                    Amazon prime Video
                    <i class="fas fa-chevron-right float-right"></i>
                    <div class="sub-cat-section">
                        <div class="ul-sub-cat">
                            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                <li class="list-sub-cat">
                                    <a href="#" class="sub-link">
                                        first
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="list-sub-cat">
                                    <a href="#" class="sub-link">
                                        first
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="list-sub-cat">
                                    <a href="#" class="sub-link">
                                        first
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="list-sub-cat">
                                    <a href="#" class="sub-link">
                                        first
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="list-sub-cat">
                                    <a href="#" class="sub-link">
                                        first
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="item-cat">
                    Amazon Prime Music
                    <i class="fas fa-chevron-right float-right"></i>
                    <div class="sub-cat-section">
                        <div class="ul-sub-cat">
                            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                <li class="list-sub-cat">
                                    <a href="#" class="sub-link">
                                        first
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="list-sub-cat">
                                    <a href="#" class="sub-link">
                                        first
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="list-sub-cat">
                                    <a href="#" class="sub-link">
                                        first
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="list-sub-cat">
                                    <a href="#" class="sub-link">
                                        first
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="list-sub-cat">
                                    <a href="#" class="sub-link">
                                        first
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

#### CSS

```
.main-drop-down{
    top:-7px;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    display: none;
    z-index:22;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden; 
}
.drop-cat{
position: absolute;
left: 166px;
width: 230px;
background: #fff;
height: 468px;
top:-10px;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
border:1px solid #fafafa;
border-radius: 2px;

}
.drop-cat::before{
    content: "";
position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
height: 0;
width: 0;
border-left: 5px solid transparent;
border-right: 5px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 5px solid #fff;
left: 70px;
}
.custom-li{
    padding: 1rem .2rem 1rem .2rem;
}
.item-cat{
    margin-left:.2rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding:.2rem 0 .2rem 0;
}
.item-cat:hover{
    color:lightcoral;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.item-cat:hover > i{
    color:#000 !important; 
}
.sub-cat-section{
position: absolute;
height: auto;
background-color: #fff;
width: 468px;
left: 229px;
top:0;
visibility: hidden;
height: 100%;
}
.active-sub-cat{
display: block;
visibility: visible;
}
.active-cat{
    display: block;
    visibility:visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
.sub-cat-section img{
    bottom:0;
    position: absolute;
    clear: both;
}
.sub-cat-section > .ul-sub-cat{
    padding:1rem;
}
.ul-sub-cat .list-sub-cat{
    padding:1rem .5rem 1rem .5rem;
}
.nav-item.dropdown{
    z-index:0;
}
```

#### JavaScript

```
let list=document.querySelectorAll(".item-cat");
list.forEach(function(elArg){
    elArg.addEventListener("mouseover",function(ev){
       let childIn=this.children[1];

       childIn.classList.add("active-sub-cat");
    })
    elArg.addEventListener("mouseleave",function(ev){
        let childOut=this.children[1];

        childOut.classList.remove("active-sub-cat");
    })
});
let nav=document.querySelector(".nav-item.dropdown");
let drp=document.querySelector(".main-drop-down");
nav.addEventListener("mouseenter",function(ev){
    document.querySelector(".main-drop-down").classList.add("active-cat");
});
drp.addEventListener("mouseleave",function(ev){
    document.querySelector(".main-drop-down").classList.remove("active-cat");
})
```

#### Attempt

I excepted these dropdown values from a JSON value, same HTML structure:

```
    let list=document.querySelectorAll(".item-cat");
    list.forEach(function(elArg){
        elArg.addEventListener("mouseover",function(ev){
           let childIn=this.children[1];
          
           childIn.classList.add("active-sub-cat");
        })
        elArg.addEventListener("mouseleave",function(ev){
            let childOut=this.children[1];
          
            childOut.classList.remove("active-sub-cat");
        })
    });
    let nav=document.querySelector(".nav-item.dropdown");
    let drp=document.querySelector(".main-drop-down");
    nav.addEventListener("mouseenter",function(ev){
        document.querySelector(".main-drop-down").classList.add("active-cat");
    });
    drp.addEventListener("mouseleave",function(ev){
        document.querySelector(".main-drop-down").classList.remove("active-cat");
    })
    body{
        background-color: darkcyan;
    }
    .main-drop-down{
        top:-7px;
        right:0;
        left:0;
        display: none;
        z-index:22;
        position: relative;
        opacity: 0;
        visibility: hidden; 
    }
    .drop-cat{
    position: absolute;
    left: 166px;
    width: 230px;
    background: #fff;
    height: 468px;
    top:-10px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border:1px solid #fafafa;
    border-radius: 2px;

    }
    .drop-cat::before{
        content: "";
    position: absolute;
        top: -5px;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #fff;
    left: 70px;
    }
    .custom-li{
        padding: 1rem .2rem 1rem .2rem;
    }
    .item-cat{
        margin-left:.2rem;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding:.2rem 0 .2rem 0;
    }
    .item-cat:hover{
        color:lightcoral;
        font-weight: 600;
    }
    .item-cat:hover > i{
        color:#000 !important; 
    }
    .sub-cat-section{
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 468px;
    left: 229px;
    top:0;
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    }
    .active-sub-cat{
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
    }
    .active-cat{
        display: block;
        visibility:visible;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    .sub-cat-section img{
        bottom:0;
        position: absolute;
        clear: both;
    }
    .sub-cat-section > .ul-sub-cat{
        padding:1rem;
    }
    .ul-sub-cat .list-sub-cat{
        padding:1rem .5rem 1rem .5rem;
    }
    .nav-item.dropdown{
        z-index:0;
    }
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
     <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-primary">
            <a class="navbar-brand text-white" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown"
                aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-white" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button"
                            data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Dropdown link
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="main-drop-down">
            <div class="drop-cat">
                <ul class="list-unstyled custom-li">
                    <li class="item-cat">
                        Echo & Alexa
                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right float-right"></i>
                        <div class="sub-cat-section">
                            <div class="ul-sub-cat">
                                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                    <li class="list-sub-cat">
                                        <a href="#" class="sub-link">
                                            first
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="list-sub-cat">
                                        <a href="#" class="sub-link">
                                            first
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="list-sub-cat">
                                        <a href="#" class="sub-link">
                                            first
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="list-sub-cat">
                                        <a href="#" class="sub-link">
                                            first
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="list-sub-cat">
                                        <a href="#" class="sub-link">
                                            first
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <img src="https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/31/img18/AmazonDevices/Neel/GW/500x450_Flyout-new._CB456065619_.png"
                                alt="img" class="img-fluid" />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="item-cat">
                        Fire Tv Stick
                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right float-right"></i>
                        <div class="sub-cat-section">
                            <div class="ul-sub-cat">
                                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                    <li class="list-sub-cat">
                                        <a href="#" class="sub-link">
                                            first
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="list-sub-cat">
                                        <a href="#" class="sub-link">
                                            first
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="list-sub-cat">
                                        <a href="#" class="sub-link">
                                            first
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="list-sub-cat">
                                        <a href="#" class="sub-link">
                                            first
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="list-sub-cat">
                                        <a href="#" class="sub-link">
                                            first
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="item-cat">
                        Kindle E-Reader & eBook
                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right float-right"></i>
                        <div class="sub-cat-section">
                            <div class="ul-sub-cat">
                                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                    <li class="list-sub-cat">
                                        <a href="#" class="sub-link">
                                            first
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="list-sub-cat">
                                        <a href="#" class="sub-link">
                                            first
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="list-sub-cat">
                                        <a href="#" class="sub-link">
                                            first
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="list-sub-cat">
                                        <a href="#" class="sub-link">
                                            first
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="list-sub-cat">
                                        <a href="#" class="sub-link">
                                            first
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li class="item-cat">
                        Amazon prime Video
                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right float-right"></i>
                        <div class="sub-cat-section">
                            <div class="ul-sub-cat">
                                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                    <li class="list-sub-cat">
                                        <a href="#" class="sub-link">
                                            first
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="list-sub-cat">
                                        <a href="#" class="sub-link">
                                            first
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="list-sub-cat">
                                        <a href="#" class="sub-link">
                                            first
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="list-sub-cat">
                                        <a href="#" class="sub-link">
                                            first
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="list-sub-cat">
                                        <a href="#" class="sub-link">
                                            first
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="item-cat">
                        Amazon Prime Music
                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right float-right"></i>
                        <div class="sub-cat-section">
                            <div class="ul-sub-cat">
                                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                    <li class="list-sub-cat">
                                        <a href="#" class="sub-link">
                                            first
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="list-sub-cat">
                                        <a href="#" class="sub-link">
                                            first
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="list-sub-cat">
                                        <a href="#" class="sub-link">
                                            first
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="list-sub-cat">
                                        <a href="#" class="sub-link">
                                            first
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="list-sub-cat">
                                        <a href="#" class="sub-link">
                                            first
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```